# Ember Accessing component's variable to other controller

Tags: ember.js

How can I access a variable declared in `/component/sales-order.js` from `/routes/sales-order.js`

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean a property of the Ember component? Also, why is this tagged `ember-data`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a **property** of the component, then basically you can't, and shouldn't. Why do you want to?

A route manages the route; it doesn't know about the details of what is eventually being rendered. A route might, for example, instantiate the same component twice. Then which once would you want to retrieve the value from?

The fact you feel the need to do this indicates some kind of problem with the way your app is structured.

Looking at this as a more general problem of how to communicate between component and route, there are various approaches, but the most basic one is to have the component send an action upward:

```
// thing/route.js
// Define the ultimate action to be invoked.
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    hiccup() { console.log("Hiccup!"); }
  }
});

// thing/template.hbs
// Invoke the component, and tie the action to something specific
{{component action='hiccup'}}

// component/component.js
// Define the component with an action.
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    go() { this.sendAction(); }
  }
});

//component/template.hbs
// Provide a button
<button {{action 'go'}}>Go!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you first export it and then import it

exporting in `/component/sales-order.js`

```
export const MY_VARIABLE = 2;
```

importing in `/routes/sales-order.js`

```
import { MY_VARIABLE } from '../components/sales-order'
console.log(MY_VARIABLE) // 2
```